# Multiple queries in a stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables.  One with 37 thousand records and another with 27 thousand records. I am building kind of a search engine. I am using auto complete for my text box so it can give suggestions like google gives whenever I write any word or any product, I can select that Name and display records ..

I have a stored procedure which should execute all the queries at once but either I am unable to execute all the queries at the same time or don't know how to combine the results. I am having problems that sometimes only the first query works, and sometimes all the records suggestions displayed. So basically I am asking how to execute all the queries in the stored procedure in SQL.

my SP is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpGetProductNames]  
@term nvarchar(MAX)

AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX)
  SET @Name=@term

   select Name from DARAZLISTING where Name like 'laptop%' OR Name like 'women kurta%' OR Name like 'Men kurta%' OR Name like 'HP LAPTOPS%' OR Name like 'Apple%' OR Name like 'daraz products%'
    UNION ALL
    select Name from SHOPHIVELISTING where Name like 'laptop%' OR Name like 'women kurta%' OR Name like 'Men kurta%' OR Name like 'HP LAPTOPS%' OR Name like 'Apple%' OR Name like 'shophive products%'
    UNION ALL
    select TOP 10 Name from DARAZLISTING where Name  like '%'+ @term + '%' OR Name like '%'+ @term OR Name like @term +'%'
     UNION ALL
    select TOP 10 Name from SHOPHIVELISTING where Name like '%'+ @term +'%' OR Name like '%'+ @term OR Name like @term + '%'
END
```

Comment: When you dont get results as expected,run  below query by passing parameter and see if you are getting results.."select TOP 10 Name from DARAZLISTING where Name  like '%'+ term + '%' OR Name like '%'+ term OR Name like term +'%'.."

Comment: That looks like a very heavy query in sql. I would recommend you use Full Text Search which can provide an index on the terms so you do not have to execute table scans (what you are doing with `LIKE '%..`). As to why you are not getting results it could be because I do not see [SET NOCOUNT ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)

Comment: Your stored procedure will execute all the UNIONed queries.   If you don't see the results you expect, it is probably because the data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: This is going to be super slow because you have nonSARGable predicates in your where clause. You have leading wildcards which will prevent any indexing to help. FULLTEXT search would probably help here. And do you really need to use varchar(max) for a search criteria? Surely nobody will be typing in anywhere near the 8,000 character limit of varchar.

Comment: Also this clause is redundant:OR Name like '%'+ term OR Name like term +'%'  when you have '%'+ term + '%'

Comment: @Igor any documentation or examples on Full text Search because i am not familier with it

Comment: @TheGameiswar yeah i guess i am wrong here, can u suggest something?

Comment: @SeanLange can i have any examples or explanation on Full text search so it can help me and i can use it in my searching?

Comment: @ShehrozJalil:i gave my suggestion on top comment,thats what i would do

Comment: @TheGameiswar yeah ur right but i have two tables and i think which query i write first that gives me the suggestion in my text box but when i write something related second table in second query sometimes that work fine and mostly don't

Comment: You can read more about full text search here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx